# xcode automatically indent when i press enter

Tags: xcode, xcode8

After last update of Xcode (Version 8.1 (8B62) it starts to makes auto-indentation when i press enter. I didn't figurate for I while what's going on because I was using krtl+i for re-indentation all the time. But re-indentation keeps that indentation from last line and makes me crazy. How to stop this in Xcode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Solution

I found that under the settings:

#### Preferences > text editing > indentation > automatically indent based on syntax > **Return**

[image: xcode automatically indent when i press enter fix]

unchecking the **Return** box stop that adventure.

If anyone needs the same feature off, this is the solution.